# Use web worker to stringify

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, web-worker

So I have an app that needs to `JSON.stringify` its data to put into localStorage, but as the data gets larger, this operation gets outrageously expensive.

So, I tried moving this onto a webWorker so it's off the main thread, but I'm now learning posting an object to a webWorker is even more expensive than stringifying it.

So I guess I'm asking, is there any way whatsoever to get `JSON.stringify` off the main thread, or at least make it less expensive?

I'm familiar with `fast-json-stringify`, but I don't think I can feasibly provide a complete schema every time...

Comment: How large is this data? AFAIK, localStorage has a limit of about 5MB in some browsers, so if it's more than that, you're going to have problems.

Comment: What about Transferable Objects? Those pass by reference instead of copy.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable

Comment: Could you add the size of data that we're talking about? How large is the data set and how many bytes are you trying to parse?

Comment: @zero298 that might actually do it - I wasn't aware of those! The data rarely nears 5MB - the main issue is how _frequently_ it stringifies. When it gets bad, the main thread gets locked up 5-10 times a minute. On a MacBook Air it can pause for 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Though Workers don't have access to Storage so you'd have to pass it back as a string to the main thread anyway. I agree with previous comments we need to know more about your data (size, kind, how come it takes too long to stringify, how come you need to store it in LocalStorage?)

Comment: @zero298 turns out I'd need to convert my object to ArrayBuffer to use it as transferable, which is pretty much the same as `stringify`. I'll try using IndexedDb instead, I think I can skip stringification with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly observed that passing object to web worker costs as much as serializing it. This is because web workers also need to receive serialized data, not native JS objects, because the instance objects are bound to the JS thread they were created in.

The generic solution is applicable to many programming problems: **chose the right data structures when working with large datasets**. When data gets larger it's better sacrifice simplicity of access for performance. Thus do any of:

#### Store data in indexedDB

If your large object contains lists of the same kind of entry, use indexed DB for reading and writing and you don't need to worry about serialization at all. This will require refactor of your code, but this is the correct solution for large datasets.

#### Store data in ArrayBuffer

If your data is mostly fixed-size values, use an ArrayBuffer. ArrayBuffer can be copied or moved to web worker pretty much instantly and if your entries are all same size, serialization can be done in parallel. For access, you may write simple wrappers classes that will translate your binary data into something more readable.

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing, Tomás. IndexedDb worked a treat. Thanks so much for the thorough answer!